# Rails 6 - ActiveStorage 404 not found after sometime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Everything works ok for X days but then, something crash for random photos ...

In VIEW I display images like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(f.image_2.variant(resize_to_fill: [30,30]), 
    :alt => 'x abc' + f.username.to_s, loading: "lazy" ),
    f.image_2.variant(resize_to_limit: [800,600]),
    :class=>'large_photo_box fancybox' 
 %>
```

Class has:

```
 has_one_attached :image_1
 has_one_attached :image_2
 has_one_attached :image_3
```

Production.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

config.cache_store = :file_store, "/tmp/my_cache"
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{10.days.to_i}"
}
```

It works, but ... after X days the photo stops showing and the no photo icon for the viewer is placed.

When it works:

- when I copy URL for image in new tab - images display
- when I open chrome development tools ( CTRL + SHIFT + J ) and reload page - the photos display again

What is going on? is there any RoR programmer left in here? ;)

**I do not calculate days but maybe problem is in production.rb cache ?**

EXAMPLE OF 404 NOT FOUND URL:

https://example.com/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDVG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNbVpzTkdObE1qWjRNRGRxYmpobmNqWnZZakYzY2podFpXSnZad1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpUzJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWpJMk1UZ3dOemxmTXpneFlpNXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSnpJMk1UZ3dOemxmTXpneFlpNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWRG9SYzJWeWRtbGpaVjl1WVcxbE9ncHNiMk5oYkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMjItMDUtMjhUMDc6MzQ6MzEuNzA2WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--566629b24793a7cca81a263eeb917ecd0d616e72/2618079_381b.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that this is solution:

"To generate a permanent URL for a blob, you can pass the blob to the **url_for** view helper. This generates a URL with the blob's signed_id that is routed to the blob's RedirectController"

Will see in few days if there isn't any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want permanent url for your variants, add `public: true` for your service in `config/storage.yml`.
More [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access)

Comment: " ... URL is intended to be short-lived for security and not used directly with users ... url should only be exposed as a redirect from a stable, possibly authenticated URL. Hiding the url behind a redirect also gives you the power to change services without updating all URLs ... " soo change it to public is not a solution, it will show orginal file instead of redirection - if I understand it correctly

Comment: I try with public: true ... it doesn't change anything, photos still are invisible